# Como fazer select usando máscara na saída

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho uma tabela cliente, e um campo cpfCliente do tipo varchar.

O cpf está armazenado sem máscara. Ex:"00751595170"

Gostaria de fazer um select que formate o resultado, colocando as máscaras.
"007.515.951.70"

Comment: Porque não coloca a máscara no front-end com Javascript ou alguma função na sua View? Precisa mesmo colocar a máscara dentro do select?

Comment: Sim, preciso sim. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode selecionar partes do campo `SUBSTR`  e concatenar `CONCAT` com os símbolos para aplicar a formatação, exemplo:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT (
SUBSTR('11111111122',1,3),'.',
SUBSTR('11111111122',4,3),'.',
SUBSTR('11111111122',7,3),'-',
SUBSTR('11111111122',10)) as cpf;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/890bb/1)**